# Free ~90% Gen2 .NET heap

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, windbg, sos

We are trying to debug the memory leak on our windows hosted service. I got the process dump and started analyzing in windbg. Heapstat showing that >~90% memory in SOH is free, but not getting garbage collected. System is throwing OutOfMemory exception now.

```
0:000> !heapstat
Heap             Gen0         Gen1         Gen2          LOH
Heap0      1280897288     14491488   3047752776      5809312
Heap1       363914880     15115160   4352729656      4666416
Heap2      1703707464     30418232   2747904232     12655040
Heap3       494016304     20954808   4365778560       800136
Total      3842535936     80979688  14514165224     23930904

Free space:                                                 Percentage
Heap0      1249220440      4930840   2915300544        48424SOH: 96% LOH:  0%
Heap1       331677752      4231032   4180971712          184SOH: 95% LOH:  0%
Heap2      1681027112      6764328   2612922440      2073728SOH: 95% LOH: 16%
Heap3       462287616      5282384   4230317520           88SOH: 96% LOH:  0%
Total      3724212920     21208584  13939512216      2122424

0:000> !EEHeap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 4
------------------------------
Heap 0 (000001621d6173a0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000016882f12f60
generation 1 starts at 0x0000016882141000
generation 2 starts at 0x000001621deb1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001621deb0000  000001621deb1000  00000162d3941448  0xb5a90448(3047752776)
0000016882140000  0000016882141000  00000168cf4a2068  0x4d361068(1295388776)
Large object heap starts at 0x000001661deb1000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001661deb0000  000001661deb1000  000001661e43b4a0  0x58a4a0(5809312)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x10337b950 (4348950864) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 1 (000001621d640760)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000016672c34480
generation 1 starts at 0x0000016671dca0e8
generation 2 starts at 0x000001631deb1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001631deb0000  000001631deb1000  000001641deae150  0xffffd150(4294955344)
000001666e6b0000  000001666e6b1000  0000016688742b00  0x1a091b00(436804352)
Large object heap starts at 0x000001662deb1000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001662deb0000  000001662deb1000  000001662e324430  0x473430(4666416)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x11a502080 (4736426112) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 2 (000001621d669bb0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000016783e43538
generation 1 starts at 0x0000016782141000
generation 2 starts at 0x000001641deb1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001641deb0000  000001641deb1000  00000164c1b4c0e8  0xa3c9b0e8(2747904232)
0000016782140000  0000016782141000  00000167e970b880  0x675ca880(1734125696)
Large object heap starts at 0x000001663deb1000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001663deb0000  000001663deb1000  000001663eac29c0  0xc119c0(12655040)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x10be77328 (4494684968) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 3 (000001621d692760)
generation 0 starts at 0x000001698794b530
generation 1 starts at 0x000001698654f678
generation 2 starts at 0x000001651deb1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001651deb0000  000001651deb1000  000001661de2a808  0xfff79808(4294416392)
0000016982140000  0000016982141000  00000169a506cc60  0x22f2bc60(586333280)
Large object heap starts at 0x000001664deb1000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
000001664deb0000  000001664deb1000  000001664df74588  0xc3588(800136)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x122f689f0 (4881549808) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x44c65d6e8 (18461611752) bytes.
```

I tried looking at gchandles, and below is the result. These handle count is huge, but now we are stuck how to debug further to find the root cause.

```
!gchandles
Handles:
    Strong Handles:       130
    Pinned Handles:       16
    Async Pinned Handles: 297
    Ref Count Handles:    88
    Weak Long Handles:    1261
    Weak Short Handles:   829
    SizedRef Handles:     8
```

Most of the pinned handles are System.Object[] or System.String[], but does not help in reaching to root cause.

```
000001621d541710 Pinned      000001661dfd7498   130584                  System.Object[]
000001621d541798 Pinned      000001661df214c0    65304                  System.Object[]
000001621d5417a0 Pinned      000001621deb1420       26                  System.String
000001621d5417a8 Pinned      000001621deb1420       26                  System.String
000001621d5417d0 Pinned      000001661deb9a30    32664                  System.Object[]
000001621d5417d8 Pinned      000001661deb5a38    16344                  System.Object[]
000001621d5417e0 Pinned      000001661deb3a20     8184                  System.Object[]
000001621d5417e8 Pinned      000001661deb35e8     1048                  System.Object[]
000001621d5417f0 Pinned      000001621deb1408       24                  System.Object
000001621d5417f8 Pinned      000001661deb1038     9616                  System.Object[]
```

Is there any way to track what is causing the SOH to be fragmented and preventing this free space to reclaim?

There are no objects ready to finalize, i checked using !FinalizeQueue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Heapstat showing that >~90% memory in SOH is free, but not getting garbage collected.

If it were not garbage collected, it wouldn't be free. Did you mean "but not getting compacted"?

Do a `!dumpheap -type Free` to see what the garbage collector has already collected.

> Most of the pinned handles are System.Object[] or System.String[], but does not help in reaching to root cause.

I would say that the root cause are the pinned objects. What more root cause do you want? Now you know what you can look for in a code review. You can also have a look at the Object[] to see its contents, if that helps.

If you want a stack trace for each object, you need a dedicated tool such as [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/). If will certainly be a bit slow if you do that with 18 GB, so you should try to reproduce it in a smaller scale.

> Is there any way to track what is causing the SOH to be fragmented and preventing this free space to reclaim?

The SOH is fragmented because of pinned objects. Pinned objects prevent the SOH from being compacted, thus leaving free space where it should normally not be.

All in all, look for [`GCHandle.Alloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_GCHandle_Alloc_System_Object_) and make sure you have a `Free()` call for each object.